# i don't know where i can put C# XML Setting File

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml

i'm trying to XML Reading by using DataProvider.
i'm using VS 2015.

code is here in 'MainWindow.xaml'

```
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="XmlData" Source="/config.xml" XPath="Settings" />
</Window.Resources>
```

but, my program couldn't read xml file. i put that 'config.xml' file in '/bin/debug' and '/bin'
both are not working. but absolute path, 'c:\config.xml' is working!

where i can put xml file?? or can i use getting application path method in xml source file??

Comment: It should work if you put the file in the output folder of the .exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For relative path use [Pack URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf)

```
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="XmlData" Source="pack://application:,,,/config.xml" XPath="Settings" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick comment! but my program couldn't read xml file. /debug/ folder is correct??

Comment: From the article I linked, I believe what happens is the config.xml is "packed" or compiled into the executable.  the Pack URI from my example would be if the config.xml is at the project's root level.